# Problema con os.walk

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente código:

```
import os, sys

path = 'PLO-2007'

files = []

# r=root, d=directories, f = files

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):

    for file in f:

        if ".fits" in file:
            f.sort()
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))


for i in range(len(files)):
    print(files[i])
```

Podrian ayudarme por que al momento de imprimirme todos los archivos de una carpeta, el primer archivo me aparece con otro nombre.
¿Sera un problema del código?

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo pegar un screenshot de los archivos que tienes y hacer pruebas con 2 o 3 archivos para ver el comportamiento del código.

Comment: Estas ordenando `f.sort()` dentro del mismo `for`, entiendo que eso lo deberías hacer antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que estás ordenando la lista de ficheros cada vez con 'f.sort()'.

Si sacas esta instrucción fuera del for, funciona sin problema.

```
import os, sys

path = 'PLO-2007'

files = []

# r=root, d=directories, f = files

    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):

        f.sort()
        for file in f:

            if ".fits" in file:

                files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

    for i in range(len(files)):
        print(files[i])
```